# Reinstalling Failed Windows Updates

Tags: windows-vista, updates

I had a problem with a Vista machine that refused to install updates. I have solved this issue but when I look at the update history there are LOADS of failed updates that need to be reinstalled...however, Windows is reporting that it is up to date.

There are a few applications that are failing to install on the system because Windows is not 100 percent updated.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to be a little more clear.  You said you fixed your update problem, but you are having issues updating?  And you are looking at the update history and seeing failed...  are you sure the update didnt install successfully later?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of terrorizing the system by installing all of the updates at once, install the required updates in chronological order, restarting every time when prompted to do so.

For instance, there are two security updates from January 1, 2005. Install ONLY those updates, then restart.

This process may be a bit time consuming, but it worked for me.